# How to see whole network on a mac?

Tags: network

I am new to the apple world and finding out some "how to stuff". One of the things I am looking for is the Microsoft equivalent of the "network center".

Everything works on my mac network-wise. However, I would like to see all devices in the network. For instance all my Sonos devices. If something is not working I was used to quickly open the network overview in Windows and see whether all devices where at least visible in the network.

How do I do this on a Mac?

Answer (score 3):

In Finder, go to the highest level available by repeatedly pressing Command-Up, or by right clicking the current folder name in the title bar and selecting the bottom entry.

From this location (called "Arnoud's Macbook Pro" or something), you should see a folder called "Network." This will show you a variety of network shares.

To see every device advertising itself on the network, check out [Bonjour Browser](http://tildesoft.com/), which will display all registered zeroconf devices.

Comment: Thanks for the two answers. I downloaded Bonjour Browser and this now also shows my Apple TV and my Network Printer. Both are not visible standard under Network in Finder. What I still miss is my 8-ish Sonos devices which work perfectly (I can still see them in the network from my Windows laptop under Network) but are not visible from my Mac. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sonos devices use UPnP not Bonjour (my mistake). OS X does not support this out of the box, so to send music to them you need a UPnP client. Try PS3 Media Server, or use the Sonos software for mac from http://www.sonos.com/support

Comment: Aha, that explains a lot. It is not that I want to do something with the Sonos deivices, I just want to see them. This goes for everything (like my network printer, the Apple TV, connected iPhones through Wifi etc). Is there no piece of software you know off that simply pictures me the whole network, irrespective of protocols etc. Just so I have at one glance an overview like I had in the Network Center of Microsoft? If necessary I am even willing to pay a few euros for such an app.

Comment: This sound perhaps strange but it always has been my starting point in case something is not working. Example: no prints out of printer, first check that printer is still correctly included in the network, one of the Sonos zones not working, first check whether it still is correctly included in the network, etc. etc. Thanks.

Comment: I by now found an App called "IP Scanner". It seems to do what I want: give me a picture of the whole network and everything attached to that network. However no reviews. Any experience with this APP on this forum, or a better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Provided you're on the network already, just open a Finder window and look under SHARED on the left pane. All computers on your subnet should show up there, provided they have sharing turned on on their computers.

Depending on your servers and stuff you might need to configure them to enable AFP (Apple Filing Protocol) or SMB (Server Message Block).

In some odd cases the firewall can block other devices, so try turning it off if the above doesn't work

Comment: I by now found an App called "IP Scanner". It seems to do what I want: give me a picture of the whole network and everything attached to that network. However no reviews. Any experience with this APP on this forum, or a better alternative?